# Rigorous proof of $f'(c)=0$ where $c$ is a global maximum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

My question is with regard to whether my following 'proof' is wrong or if it is an acceptable way to show that at a maximum $c$, $f'(c)=0$.

A function  $f : [a,b]$ $ \to\Bbb R$ is differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$ and $f$ achieves a global maximum at $c$. Prove $f'(c)=0$.

My Proof:

Since $f(c)$ is a global maximum then $f(c)\ge f(x) \forall x \in (a,b)$.

Using the definition of a derivative $f'(c)=\lim \limits_{x\to c}\frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$

we see that $f(x)-f(c)$ will always be negative.

If we approach the limit from the left then $\lim \limits_{x\to c^-}f'(c)>0$,

and if we approach the limit from the right then $\lim \limits_{x\to c^+}f'(c)<0$.

But we know that $f'(c)$ exists so $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: (+1) 99% correct. Your inequalities after "approach the limit" should be non-strict.

Comment: This looks about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost! It doesn't make sense to write $\lim_{x\to c^-}f'(c)$ because there is no variable $x$ in the limit. Remember that $f'(c)$ is already a limit. Surely you mean just $\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x)}{x-c}$.

Also, as Umberto P. points out, all the inequalities should be non-strict. To double-check yourself, you can run through the proof with a simple example, the constant function $f(x)=0$. Make sure you're not saying anything wrong about that function.